# HOw can I write a JQuery function to take background-image from an inline-style div and put it in an image tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

How do I write a function that will take a background-image from inline styles for a div and remove the div and in it's place it will use an `<img>` tag?

Here's what my divs look like:

```
<div class="img_is" style="background-image: url(//domain.com/images/image1.png);"></div>
```

I will have several of those divs and the img source will be different for each.

So now how can i write a function that will take the src of the background-image and put them in an `<img src>` and hide the div?

I thought of this code but couldn't really figure out how to reverse it.  Please help.  Please tell me if you see something wrong or if you have any questions about this.

My code:

```
var images = $('li > img');
images.each(function(){
    $(this).parent().css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).attr('src') + ')');
    $(this).hide(); // to hide it
    $(this).remove(); // to remove it from the markup
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one option which uses the overload of `replaceWith` that takes a function:

http://jsfiddle.net/fQ2t3/

```
$('.img_is').replaceWith(function () {
    return $('<img/>', {
        src: $(this).css('background-image').replace(/url\(([^\)]+)\)/g, '$1')
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jason but it wasn't able to work.  I added a path to a real image but it still won't render int he fiddle.  Please see.  Thanks!

Comment: @ariel inspect the dom, the div should have been replaced with an image, wasn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to remove the wrapping `url(...)` from the image before adding it to the `src` of the new image.

```
function(){
  var src = $(this).css('background-image').slice(4,-1),
      img = new Image();

  img.src = src;

  $(this).replaceWith(img);

}
```

Something like this should do the trick.